# What's wrong with my post operation

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a webapi2 which has signature

```
[Route("add/usertorole")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddUserToRole([FromBody] UserRoleRequest request)
```

My UserRoleRequst Object looks like

```
public class UserRoleRequest
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName="UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RoleName")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling this API as follows

```
UserRoleRequest request = new UserRoleRequest() { UserName = userName, RoleName = roleName };
string reqStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
string api = "api/myapi/add/usertorole";
WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST"
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
byte[] byteArray = new byte[reqStr.Length * sizeof(char)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(reqStr.ToCharArray(), 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
         rawData= reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Status Code: {0}, Status Description: {1}", resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription));
}

Console.WriteLine(rawData);
```

When I debug this code the call goes inside my webapi2 method but the input parameter is NULL.

why is my input not being serialized correctly on the server side?

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether it is related to your problem, but note that you copy 16-bit character codes verbatim into the byte array used for the request, which corresponds to UTF-16 encoding and not to UTF-8 as you specified as content type.

Comment: You nailed it. right answer. Also I had to convert the json to a base64 string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working code. thanks to elgonzo.

Two things are different from my previous code.

1. charset is specified to utf-16
2. the json string is converted to base64 and then converted to bytearray.

   ```
       WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
       req.Method = post ? "POST" : "GET";                     
       req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
       req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-16";
       if (post)
       {
           byte[] byteArray = new byte[data.Length * sizeof(char)];
           Buffer.BlockCopy(data.ToCharArray(), 0, byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);                
           req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
           Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
           string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
           byte[] base64Array = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
           dataStream.Write(base64Array, 0, base64Array.Length - 1);
           dataStream.Close();
       }
   ```

Comment: +1 for name dropping :) Just kidding, in reality +1 for making the effort of reporting your fix/solution here.